# Windows Active Directory cannot show user files while on VPN

Tags: active-directory

**I have this setup with a local LAN where I have changed the main router from PFSense to a UDM PRO router and new VPN Active Directory users no longer see their documents while working remote.**

The network has several servers and one of them is a Windows Active Directory. While everything works fine if the users are working from the local network, when I connect with a VPN things are no longer working.

The VPN is set using L2TP with a pre-sared key, username and pass. The clients are using the native windows VPN client. Prior to the switch to Unifi the clients were using OpenVPN app as it was set in PFSense.

I can log in users using a VPN on the domain, yet I do not have access to the user files or shared AD resources.

I can however see the AD in the network, I can ping it and there is no Firewall rule blocking traffic in or out. Also I checked the old PFSense config for special port fw rules and there are no rules related to the AD.

I have set the local DNS to the IP of the AD controller so that all requests related to the domain are routed properly. The domain is defined as company.local so the local DNS takes care of this translation to the IP of the AD server.

Comment: So something is blocking SMB traffic. Active directory is probably a red herring; that's used for authentication, not file sharing. Check that your UDM does not block TCP/UDP port 445.

Comment: tried with PowerShell tnc and result is test succeeded so the port is not blocked.